# Laravel 4 stores index instead of values in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello want to save some data in database. I have created a form and also get data from form to controller and save in database. The problem is that instead of saving values typed by user it is saving the order in which this values are in dropdown list. 
create.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'cars', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
 <div class="form-group">
         {{ Form::label('id', 'Color',array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
            <div class="col-lg-8">
               {{ Form::select('color', $color, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
{{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
```

CarController.php

```
public function store() {
   $data = new Car;
   $data->color = Input::get('color');
     $data->save();
     // redirect
     return Redirect::to('cars');
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Show us what you get from `var_dump(Input::get('color'));`

Comment: string '12' (length=2)

Comment: and it saves value 12 in DB

Comment: That's because you have id stored in `value` attribute from `<option>`. You should store there color name too. Show me how are you declaring `$color` variable

Comment: I am getting it from database. $color = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Color', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Color');return View::make('pages.create', array(
                    'color' => $color
        ));

Comment: in the dropdown it shows the list of values and I select one of them for example "white" and then it saves in db a nr

Comment: Well, thats strange, you are getting colors correctly. But try to add second argument in `lists()`: `$color = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Color', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Color', 'Color');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to change a way how Arual was getting colors from:

```
$color = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Color', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Color');
```

to:

```
$color = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Color', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Color', 'Color');
```

He also asked why. Its hard to say, i checked Laravel source code, but i should study much longer to figure whats going on. Probably `id` column is taken as `$key` attribute if not specified in `lists` function.

Comment: Because lists('value','key') returns array('key'=>'value') and Form::select takes that 'key' as html OPTION value (which is passed from the form) and 'value' is what is displayed in the option. So basically your solution works as long as there are no duplicates in the color column.

Comment: Ofcourse you're right. But the question was why `lists('Color')` doesn't work correctly and makes `array('id'=>'Color')`

Comment: Yes, and the answer is in my comment :) It didn't store the 'id' but simple numeric array key, while your solution with passing Color as a 2nd argument overriden numeric keys of that array doing what OP needed.